# when display activity as dialog facing issue

Tags: android

I added this in manifest

```
theme.dialog <activity android:name=".Disclaimer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

in my activity still I am not getting this as dialog.

Please help to fix it

```
<activity android:name=".Disclaimer"               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Comment: If the answers already given don't work, you need to supply more information for folks to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`

in your Manifest file what you are doing is

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

which is for hiding the Title bar of the Activity.

Answer (score 2):

set your activity theme to dialog, by adding following line in corresponding activity:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: i added this still am not getting